# AngularJS redirect controller and history back issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I need help with external redirecting in AngularJS.

This is my route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/route1/', {
    template: html_externalRedirect,
    resolve: resolver(['core/controllers/ExternalRedirectController'])
});
```

This is my redirect controller:

```
define(['myApp',], function (myApp) {
   'use strict';
   myApp.lazy.controller('ExternalRedirectController', ['$location', '$window',
       function ($location, $window) {
          $window.location = baseUrl + $location.path();
   }]);
});
```

Redirect works successfully, but when I click 'back' browser button, it redirects me to 'not found' page. Seems like, records in window history are wrong.
Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you didn't define the default route to $routeProvider.
Please add either of two options to solve this problem:

- `.when("/", {
      template: html_externalRedirect
  })`
- otherwise({
      template: html_externalRedirect
  });

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it in my question, but I have a default route to $routeProvider.
How it can help me? I don't exactly understand.